# Pandas Cumulative Sum of Difference Between Value Counts in Two Dataframe Columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, series

The charts below show my basic challenge: subtract NUMBER OF STOCKS WITH DATA END from NUMBER OF STOCKS WITH DATA START. The challenge I am having is that the date range for each series does not match so I need to merge both sets to a common date range, perform the subtraction, and save results to a new comma seperated value file.

Input data in file named 'meta.csv' contains 3187 lines. Fields per line are data for ticker, start, & end. Head and tail as shown here:

```
0000 ticker,start,end
0001 A,1999-11-18,2016-12-27
0002 AA,2016-11-01,2016-12-27
0003 AAL,2005-09-27,2016-12-27
0004 AAMC,2012-12-13,2016-12-27
0005 AAN,1984-09-07,2016-12-27
...
3183 ZNGA,2011-12-16,2016-12-27
3184 ZOES,2014-04-11,2016-12-27
3185 ZQK,1990-03-26,2015-09-09
3186 ZTS,2013-02-01,2016-12-27
3187 ZUMZ,2005-05-06,2016-12-27
```

Python code and console output:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('meta.csv')
s = df.groupby('start').size().cumsum()
e = df.groupby('end').size().cumsum()
#s.plot(title='NUMBER OF STOCKS WITH DATA START',
#       grid=True,style='k.')
#e.plot(title='NUMBER OF STOCKS WITH DATA END',
#       grid=True,style='k.')

print(s.head(5))
print(s.tail(5))
print(e.tail(5))

OUT:
start
1962-01-02    11
1962-11-19    12
1970-01-02    30
1971-08-06    31
1972-06-01    54
dtype: int64
start
2016-07-05    3182
2016-10-04    3183
2016-11-01    3184
2016-12-05    3185
2016-12-08    3186
end
2016-12-08     544
2016-12-15     545
2016-12-16     546
2016-12-21     547
2016-12-27    3186
dtype: int64
```

Chart output when comments removed for code shown above:

[image: cumulative number of stocks based on start date]

[image: cumulative number of stocks based on end date]

I want to create one population file with the date and number of stocks with active data which should have a head and tail shown as follows:

```
date,num_stocks
1962-01-02,11
1962-11-19,12
1970-01-02,30
1971-08-06,31
1972-06-01,54
...
2016-12-08,2642
2016-12-15,2641
2016-12-16,2640
2016-12-21,2639
2016-12-27,2639
```

The ultimate goal is to be able to plot the number of stocks with data over any specified date range by reading the population file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the crucial tip provided by piRSquared I solved the challenge using this code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('meta.csv')
x = df.start.value_counts().sub(df.end.value_counts(), fill_value=0)
x.iloc[-1] = 0
r = x.cumsum()
r.to_csv('pop.csv')
z = pd.read_csv('pop.csv', index_col=0, header=None)
z.plot(title='NUMBER OF STOCKS WITH DATA',legend=None,
       grid=True,style='k.')
```

'pop.csv' file head/tail:

```
1962-01-02  11.0
1962-11-19  12.0
1970-01-02  30.0
1971-08-06  31.0
1972-06-01  54.0
...
2016-12-08  2642.0
2016-12-15  2641.0
2016-12-16  2640.0
2016-12-21  2639.0
2016-12-27  2639.0
```

Chart:

[image: Number of Stocks with Data]

Answer (score 2):

To align the dates with their respective counts.  I'd take the difference of `pd.Series.value_counts`

```
df.start.value_counts().sub(df.end.value_counts(), fill_value=0)

1984-09-07    1.0
1990-03-26    1.0
1999-11-18    1.0
2005-05-06    1.0
2005-09-27    1.0
2011-12-16    1.0
2012-12-13    1.0
2013-02-01    1.0
2014-04-11    1.0
2015-09-09   -1.0
2016-11-01    1.0
2016-12-27   -9.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you for this very useful suggestion which has helped me make a plot that looks like the correct solution to my challenge. I need to write the population file and check it over before posting an answer to my own question soon.